# create varchar sequence in ADF throw ORA-01722

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, ora-01722, bc4j

Friends i am working on jdev12c but i am facing issue i am able to create new record using bc4j tester but when i am trying to change(update) existing data it throws exception Invalid Number`Error while selecting entity for CustmerInfo: ORA-01722: invalid number`
I have searched for this error but i am not able to get solution just to provide more information I have one master and 2 child tables.In master table i have 2 column which uses DBSequence(seq and trigger from database) and one mandatory date field(timestamp).
I have found out the reason actually the customernumber column is varchar because i am concatenating the sequence with prefix and then storing it.now the problem is as soon as i change entity attribute to DBSEQUENCE it throws invalid number error for updation

Comment: DBSequence is a number type column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBSequence should only be used if the value you are getting is populated form a DB Sequence - which would be a number.
If you are manually populating that field - then use a regular String type for the field.